# Resizing the content UIView in a UIScrollView, is there a good way to do this without having to do any calculations?

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView, the frame size is that of the screen. Inside the scrollview is my content UIView. This view has a number of buttons in it. These are dynamic and the number will grow over time so I need the content UIView's size to also be increased. Is there a good way to get the UIView to resize to fit around all the subviews inside (i.e the UIButtons)?

I tried this method:

```
[self.content sizeToFit];
self.scrollView.contentSize=self.content.frame.size;
```

Doesn't seem to be doing anything though.

Answer (score 0):

The default implementation of `sizeThatFits:` on `UIView` doesn't affect any change when using `sizeToFit`. Instead, you could subclass `UIView` and use this heavy-handed approach:

```
@interface MyView : UIView
@end
@implementation MyView
- (CGSize)sizeThatFits:(CGSize)size {
  CGSize contentSize = CGSizeZero;
  for (UIView *subview in [self subviews]) {
    contentSize.width = MAX(contentSize.width, CGRectGetMaxX(subview.frame));
    contentSize.height = MAX(contentSize.height, CGRectGetMaxY(subview.frame));
  }
  size.width = MIN(size.width, contentSize.width);
  size.height = MIN(size.height, contentSize.height);
  return size;
}
@end
```